# Set different path headers in S function Matlab

Tags: matlab, header, s-function

I would like to set paths headers in S function in Matlab to do that Matlab goes to those paths to find headers.
I give an example:
header 1 in path 1 (current folder matlab)
header 2 in path 2
header 3 in path 2

I call headers in S Function code like this:

## include "header1.h"

Then header1 has the next include:

## include "path2/header2.h"

then Matlab get fine the header 2, but the problem is when header 2 call header 3 like this:

## include "header3.h"

So Matlab tries to get header 3 from current folder (path1) but header 3 is in path2.

So how can I set headers' paths? So do that Matlab find header in different paths?

Comment: It will be easier if you use Matlab's legacy code generator ( LCT ) to create sfunctions

Comment: I can't use that becaouse I have already done in the other way.

Comment: but you could still use it just to see how it would do it, and then copy that logic over to your "real" code

Comment: It is not MATLAB. The C compiler compiles these files and looks for headers in the include paths specified. Try specifying additional include paths using -I option when you build this using mex.

Comment: Yes. The last comment here is the solution! Thanks!